# how to mask/unmask a field by changing type and retaining all old events (using dojo in IE)

Tags: events, dojo, mask

I am trying to mask/unmask a dojo text field upon clicking a mask/unmask-link..
On clicking this link I am changing the type property of the dojo-text field to "password" and vice versa..
but this is not working in IE8,9,10 versions.. works in IE11/Firefox though..
when searching google the advice was to recreate the same field with the existing properties and events with the needed type..

I can recreate the field, but I am just wondering **how to get all the existing-events(dojo) of the current field**.

Can somebody help me ?

I am also looking for any other approach other than this to handle this mask/unmask use-case, but considering using Dojo.
I'm using Dojo 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of Internet Explorer the type attribute of an input field is considered readonly ([IE6, IE7, IE8, IE9?](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/09/bug-237-type-is-readonly-attribute-in.html)) and the browser will not let you change it. (This may also be the case if not running in Standards Mode - though I haven't tested this)

To overcome this you may need to remove it from the DOM, and create a new input of the type you want, and re-insert it.

Comment: Yes Scunlife, you are right and I agree.. but I am looking for doing this in Dojo and more importantly looking for how to get the events of an existing field using dojo api, i could not find relevant api to get the list of events in dojo..

Comment: You may be better off (if the API isn't clear) to show/hide 2 versions of the field (one text, one password) and just copy the value across.